# Is there a place in Stack Exchange that is suited for explaining articles?

Tags: discussion

#### Intro

As part of some work I'm doing for a course, I need to review/learn two article by Dijkstra. Not the most famous ones, but some on the topic of self stabilizing. I was thinking that after going through them, I could probably explain them to others and there are some proofs there that were not included that I might try and add (or just a way to prove them, or something similar).

#### Question

Is there a specific site or method that can be used to explain an article and maybe add additional material (from other articles or self added work) and is there an interest in it?

**options:**

1. Q&A style piece asking about the article and then answering it in https://cs.stackexchange.com/.
2. Add something in the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) page under the relevant tag.

I am asking in relevance to the field I'm working on, but I suppose that this is relevant for other fields as well (like [chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) or [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/)).

Happy to hear your input.

Comment: Given that you asked this question only an hour ago, it may be worth holding back on accepting an answer for some more time to allow further answers to come in?

Comment: Why does this have to be on Stack Exchange? There are many other avenues to self-publish available on the internet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange actually **encourages** answering your own question. Moreover, you can post question *and* an answer in at *the same time*:

[image]

From [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to answer
> their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
> answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
> that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
> okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Dijkstra's algorithms are suitable for the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Both options are fine as long as they meet the standards.

Comment: I know there is a Q&A option - that's why I listed it as my first option. I was wondering if this is a good idea for *articles*